# How does the SelectPercentile score function work?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-mining, dimensionality-reduction

Recently I am studying Dimension Reduction methods and I found that the python package "sklearn.feature_selection" seems pretty useful, but the problem is the method SelectPercentile.fit doesn't explain how it calculates the score function.

[link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectPercentile.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectPercentile.fit)

Does anyone know how it works?

For instance, if I select "SelectFdr" for "SelectPercentile", and the SelectFdr method's criterion is depending on each p-value of each feature.  How do I know which ways does "SelectFdr" sets hypothesis or defines error rates?

SelectFdr method which subscription is "Select features based on an estimated false discovery rate."  So it must be using some classification methods at first, so it can calculate the false discovery rate, my problem is what classification method is in "SelectPercentile".

Comment: I think the user can provide their own score function in constructor. The default function is is [f_classif](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.f_classif.html#sklearn.feature_selection.f_classif).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see comment of source code in below link:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ef5cb84a/sklearn/feature_selection/univariate_selection.py#L368

you can select score function as parameter. if you don't determine function , default function is ANOVA.

Comment: For instance, if I select "SelectFdr" for "SelectPercentile", and the SelectFdr method's criterion is depending on each p-value of each feature.  How do I know which ways does "SelectFdr" sets hypothesis or defines error rates?

A

Comment: @MarcusLin in this instance, selectFdr use Benjamini-Hochberg procedure. in source code of this library each method has comment that say what to do.

Comment: I didn't think it through. Thanks again.